# MySQL performance issue with large tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've been asked to develop a web software able to store some reading data from heat metering device and to divide the heat expenses among all the flat owner. I chose to work in php with MySQL engine MyISAM.

I was not used to work with large data, so i simply created a logical database where we have:

1. a table for building, with an id as primary key indexed (now we have ~1200
   buildings in the db)
2. a table with all the flats in all the buildings, with an id as primary key indexed and the building_id to link to the building (around 32k+ flats in total)
3. a table with all the heaters in all the flats, with an id as primary key indexed and the flat_id to link to the flat (around 280k+ heaters)
4. a table with all the reading value, with the timestamp of the reading, an id as primary key and the heater_id to link to the heater (around 2.7M+ reading now)

There is also a separate table, linked to the building, where are stored the starting date and the end date between which the division of expenses have to be done.

When it is necessary to get all the data from a building, the approach i used is to get raw data from DB with single query, elaborate in php, than make the next query.

So here is roughly the operation sequence i used:

1. get the starting and end date from the specific table with a single query
2. store the dates in a php variable
3. get all the flats of the building: `SELECT * FROM flats where building_id=my_building_id`
4. parse all the data in php with a php while cycle
5. on each step of the while cycle i make a query getting all the heaters of that specific flat: `SELECT * FROM heaters where flat_id=my_flat_id`
6. parse all the data of the heaters with a php while cycle
7. on each step of this inner while cycle i'll get the last reading value of that specific heater: `SELECT * FROM reading_values where heater_id=my_heater_id AND data<my_data`

Now the problem is that i have serious performance issue.

Before someone point it out, i cannot get only reading value jumping all the first 6 steps of the list above, since i need to print bills and on each bill i have to write all flat information and all heaters information, so i have to get all the flats and heaters data anyway.

So I'd like some suggestions on how to improve script performance:

- all the tables are indexed, but i have to add some index somewhere else?
- would using a single query with subquery instead of several one among php code improve performance?
- any other suggestions?

I haven't inserted specific code as i think it would have made the question too heavy, but if asked i could insert some.

Comment: Have you benchmarked your code to see where the biggest bottleneck is? For example, is it a particular MySQL query, or is it the PHP processing the data afterwards? Dump a load of `echo microtime(true)` lines into your code and see where the biggest gap is. Then you can focus on that area, and move on to the next gap.

Comment: two things to look at, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and mysql-slow.log. These two can give you a hint which system is to blame. Although the php-based iteration with subsequent queries does sound like it may take some time.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware of the EXPLAIN command, it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Some:

1. Don't use 'SELECT *' if you can avoid it -> Just get the fields you really need
2. I didn't test it in your particular case, but usually a single query which joins all three tables should achieve much better performance rather than looping through results with php.
3. If you need to loop for some reason, then at least use mysql prepared statements, which again should increase performance given the amount of queries :)

Hope it helps!

Regards

**EDIT:**
just to exemplify an alternative query, not sure if this suits your specific needs and without testing it (which probably means I forgot something):

```
SELECT 

a.field1, 
b.field2, 
c.field3,
d.field4

FROM heaters a

JOIN reading_values b ON (b.heater_id = a.heater_id)
JOIN flats c ON (c.flat_id = a.flat_id)
JOIN buildings d ON (d.building_id = c.building_id)

WHERE 

a.heater_id = my_heater_id 
AND b.date < my_date

GROUP BY a.heater_id
```

**EDIT 2**

Following your comments, I modified the query so that it retrieves the information as you want it: Given a building id, it will list all the heaters and their newest reading value according to a given date:

```
SELECT 

a.name, 
b.name, 
c.name,
d.reading_value,
d.created

FROM buildings a

JOIN flats b ON (b.building_id = a.building_id)
JOIN heaters c ON (c.flat_id = b.flat_id)
JOIN reading_values d ON (d.reading_value_id = (SELECT reading_value_id FROM reading_values WHERE created <= my_date AND heater_id = c.heater_id ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1))

WHERE 

a.building_id = my_building_id

GROUP BY c.heater_id
```

It should be interesting to know how it performs in your environment.

Regards

Comment: There's a problem with this approach: eacher heater has several reading value associated with it. Let's suppose the heater with id 1234 has associated 15 reading values, with the above query i'll get back a row for each of the 15 reading values while i want back a single row for each heater, not more than 1. Similar problem happens with flat data: on each row where there's a heater, i have replicated all the data for the flat and all the data for the building, in this way the single resulting row is much bigger and has more replicated data that it should have

Comment: @TizianoMischi , you could use mysql's `group_concat`, but beware it has a max length limit (more than some N will be truncated)

Comment: I see. I wrongly assumed each heater would have a single reading value. Anyway, I guess you could still use reading_values as the main table (FROM) or play with the GROUP BY field to achieve the result you want. As stated, that was only to provide a sample query, but of course you might need to adapt it to your specific needs :)

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly: The main information you want to retrieve is all heaters from a given building, right? While each heater can have several reading values, you are only interested in the latest one based on a given date. Your goal is to generate a bill which contains information about the heater, its reading value corresponding to the given date and flat and building information. Is this correct?

Comment: @e.lopez yes, what you said is correct. Anyway to generate the bill i get as input value the building id and i need to retrieve also information about the building and all the flats in it.

Comment: Look at my second edit. I think it might be what you are looking for. I tested the query in SQL Fiddle.